# pixi.js - how to inset a basic image as mesh with some scattered vertices

Tags: mesh, pixi.js

New to pixi.js. My goal is to insert an image (puppet) that has some specific control points/vertices, something like this:

[image: image with random internal vertices].

It seems that `Mesh` or `SimpleMesh` is what I need to accomplish this but I'm open to other means. I've tried to research how to use these without luck. There's likely something obvious I missed, I admit.

The one example I found (https://reactpixi.org/components/mesh) doesn't explain what's going on. Since the `SimpleMesh` constructor [only requires the texture](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.SimpleMesh.html) I assume that's all it needs to display it. Yet, that example includes the `uvs` and `indices` optional parameters.

When I change the indices to `null` it no longer works and I can't understand why. Others have said it shouldn't matter.

I've boiled the example down to this short codepen: https://codepen.io/frostbitten/pen/mdXRdXv

I'm having a hard time just finding how to use these things. Like, if I need to specify the indices, how do I even start? I don't know how to format such data nor have I found a resource explaining it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve or why you have decided to use SimpleMesh, but isn't it something like pixi-spine what you need? https://pixijs.io/examples/#/plugin-spine/spineboy-pro.js

Comment: I explained what I'm trying to achieve: take a plane, divide it into triangles, control some of the vertices. Spine costs money and my goal is so simple, as simple as the mesh I want to use. Ridiculous overkill to buy spine.